# How to customize pager in dhtmlxGrid to load data dynamically on every page?

Tags: dhtmlx

When a user clicks on a page, then an evry time xml file should be loaded dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the setXMLAutlLoading() method. Its second attribute (buffer) defines the number of rows coming from the server at a time
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__dhtmlxgrid_setxmlautoloading.html